# Транзакции в коде

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, исключения, best-practice

Есть примерно такой код:

```
ПриВыходеИзВарпРежима()
{
  ДобавитьКораблиВКосмос();
  УстановитьУНихДефолтныеКоординаты();
  ...
  ВключитьЩиты();
  ОбнаружитьПротивников();
}
```

В методе `ВключитьЩиты` произошла ошибка, а значит, я хочу всё откатить назад.
С базами данных всё легко, там есть транзакции. А как быть с кодом? 
Может придумали что-то? Чтобы не писать кучу обратных шагов.

Comment: Что именно "все" вы хотите откатить назад?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте написать ваш код в стиле «опасные изменения — безопасный коммит» + иммутабельность.

```
// изменения
локальные корабли' = создать корабли с дефолтными координатами и включённым щитом();
локальный космос' = космос.ДобавитьКораблиИВернутьНовыйКосмос(корабли');
...
локальные противники' = обнаружить противников в (космос');

// безопасный коммит
космос = космос'
противники = противники'
```

Если какая-то часть из изменений вылетит — она затрагивает лишь локальные объекты, которые съест garbage collector или RAII.

---

Если все объекты у вас иммутабельны, то новый локальный космос — не расходная штука: он делит большую часть своих объектов со старым космосом.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения такой задачи используется паттерн [Memento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) ([Хранитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)).

С его помощью Вы сохраняете состояние объекта перед началом операций. А в случае ошибки - записываете сохраненное состояние обратно.

Осталось только отловить наличие ошибки. Беспроигрышный вариант - через возвращаемые значения. Еще можно воспользоваться исключениями. Но в данном случае они не очень к месту, так как это вовсе даже не исключительная ситуация, а вполне себе игровая логика. Они только добавят лишние тормоза. И размажут логику по коду не хуже, чем это делает goto.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите откатить назад. Состояние переменных, измененных в методе, в котором произошла ошибка?

Если так, то самый простой путь - это сохранить состояние всех нужных вам переменных перед вызовом метода `ВключитьЩиты()`. После чего, в случае ошибки, использовать вернуться к сохраненному состоянию.

Answer (score 0):

Я видел такую методику. Перед выполнением критичного кода, делаем копию всех переменных/объектов. Потом выполняем код. Если произошла ошибка, то просто восстанавливаем все назад. В С++ это можно сделать удобно, если написать правильные конструкторы копирования.

В чистом Си я видел другой прием. Хитрая череда goto. Где то так.

```
ПриВыходеИзВарпРежима()
{
  if (!ДобавитьКораблиВКосмос()) { goto space; }
  if (!УстановитьУНихДефолтныеКоординаты()) { goto coord; }
  ...
  if (!ВключитьЩиты()) { goto guard; }
  if (!ОбнаружитьПротивников()) {goto anemi;}
  return ok;
  anemi:
   ПровестиДиагностикуВторогоУровня();
  guard:
   ПерекалиброватьЩиты();
  coord:
    УбратьДефолтныеКоординаты();
  space:
    УбратьКораблиСКосмоса();
  return bad;
}
```

То есть, если происходит ошибка - переходим по goto на обработчики "откатки в к нормальному состоянию".

Да, я вижу, что Вы не хотите писать "обратные шаги", но иногда без них просто невозможно.